# How to store UIButton value in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uibutton, uipickerview

How to store `UIButton` value in core data.I have two button named as BloodGroup and city.
when user click on any button then `pickerview` appear at bottom and there is cancel and done button.So user select value from `UIPickerview` and click on Done button then `UIPickerview` disappear and that value displayed in `UIButton`.

Answer needed for two questions.
I want to store this value in core data.
1) how we can store this value?

second option is if we can store this value in uitextfield then it is easy.

2) can any one tell me how to pass data from selected field in button to `UITextField` ?

```
import UIKit

class Bloodbank: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var Bloodgroup: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var City: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var pickerViewObj: UIPickerView!


    @IBOutlet weak var subViewObj: UIView!



    let fruitsArrayValues = ["A+","A-","B+","B-","AB+","AB-","O+","O-"]
    let iPhoneModelArrayValues = ["Ahmedabad","Gandhinagar","Surat","Rajkot","Vadodara"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        subViewObj.hidden = true
    }

    //delegate methods.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        //dynamic delegate methods using pickerviewObj.tag
        if pickerViewObj.tag == 0 {
            return fruitsArrayValues.count
        }
        else {
            return iPhoneModelArrayValues.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        if pickerViewObj.tag == 0 {
            return "\(fruitsArrayValues[row])" //its displyed to titleForRow.
        }
        else {
            return "\(iPhoneModelArrayValues[row])"
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //valuesLbl.text = pickerDataValues[row]
    }


    @IBAction func selectItemsBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        //first they set the tag in pickerviewObj.
        subViewObj.hidden = false
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            pickerViewObj.tag = 0
        case 1:
            pickerViewObj.tag = 1
        default:
            break;
        }
        pickerViewObj.reloadAllComponents()
    }



    @IBAction func cancelBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    subViewObj.hidden = true
    }


    @IBAction func DoneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        if pickerViewObj.tag == 0 {
            let selectedIndex = pickerViewObj.selectedRowInComponent(0)
            Bloodgroup.setTitle(fruitsArrayValues[selectedIndex], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        else if pickerViewObj.tag == 1 {
            let selectedIndex = pickerViewObj.selectedRowInComponent(0)
            City.setTitle(iPhoneModelArrayValues[selectedIndex], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        subViewObj.hidden = true

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see the selected value is just a String. You can store strings in core data.

For the second question: you can get the value of the button's title with the current title method. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/currentTitle

Btw have you considered using NSUserDefaults to store this value? It might be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir,   1) as you said selected value is string,so in core data to save bloodgroup and city value ,  which things should i add as a core data attribute from abouve outlet and actions..     2) should we pass button value to second textfeild from currenttitle method..       thank you sir..   waiting for your valuable reply..

Comment: I guess you would need an entity that has two string attributes, bloodgroup, and city. But coredata might be too difficult for this project, or your skill level, userdefaults would be as simple as this: 
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(button.currentTitle, forKey: "bloodType"), and let storedBloodType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("bloodType"). I dont understand your second question. I cant see a textfield.

Comment: imagine there is textfield named as "textfielddemo".  so when user select value form pickerview then it is appear in textfielddemo.    if this happen then value of textfield is easily enter into core data.  i want core data because after entering details, it is useful in secondviewcontroller to fetch core data and uses it.    thanks VIK for your reply and once again i am waiting for your reply.